# Issues remotely editing registry keys with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I am using `Invoke-Command` to alter the property of a registry key however it seems to only work intermittently. If I enter a `PSSession` and enter the exact same code it works.

As ou can see in this example it doesn't make the changes. Does anyone know how I could make this persistently work?

`````
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock{

$RedBoxReg = get-item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Red Box Recorders Limited\RBRWSC'

$RedBoxReg | Set-ItemProperty -name RecorderAddress -value 172.20.42.18,172.25.42.40 

echo $RedBoxReg

}````

Name                           Property                                                                        PSComputerName                                                                 
----                           --------                                                                        --------------                                                                 
RBRWSC                         RecorderAddress : 172.23.90.18 172.23.90.19                                     D000499                                                                        
                               TerminalNaming  : 0
`````

Comment: _"seems to only work intermittently"_  What do you mean?  Does it always work on some servers and fail on others?  Does it fail sometimes on subsequent runs on the same server?  Different user accounts, registry keys, etc?  Are there any errors?

Comment: It seems to work on the same computer sometimes, but not others. I'm happy to scrap this approach if you can recommend another

Comment: OK, there is more. It looks like the  ````Set-ItemProperty ```` line does actually work, but the then when i echo out the variable the result i am getting doesn't show the change. Its like its a cached result or something.

Comment: The value you are echoing is the original one you read at the start of the scriptblock - it is not dynamically updated when the registry changes.    What happens if you read it again after the `Set-ItemProperty` call and echo _that_ result?

Comment: yea I tried that but i stil end up getting the old result. The change does consistently work, but its just the reporting element that is flawed.

Comment: Are you sure you've reassigned the variable? After piping `$RedBoxReg` to `Set-ItemProperty` you need to run `$RedBoxReg = Get-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Red Box Recorders Limited\RBRWSC'`, and then call `$RedBoxReg` to see the value and if the values have not changed, then there is probably something wrong with your `Set-ItemProperty` line. Any error messages from that line?